# Warning: Your pubspec.yaml includes an "author" section which is no longer used and may be removed

Tags: flutter

I want to publish my library and same as before, I have included `author` name in the `pubspec` file.
Running `flutter pub pub publish --dry-run` gives me the following warning:

```
Warning: Your pubspec.yaml includes an "author" section which is no longer used and may be removed
```

I will authorize my publishing using the email in my author value. If I remove it, how will I authorize.

I'll be thankful to know more about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `author` or `authors` to verify yourself, the new way is that you make yourself a **verified publisher**.

According to [documents](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/publishing#verified-publisher):

> #### To create a verified publisher, follow these steps:
>
> - Go to [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/).
> - Log in to pub.dev using a Google Account.
> - In the user menu in the top-right corner, select Create Publisher.
> - Enter the domain name that you want to associate with your publisher
>     (for example, dart.dev), and click Create Publisher.
> - In the confirmation dialog, select OK.
> - If prompted, complete the verification flow, which opens the [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about).
> - When adding DNS records, it may take a few hours before the Search
>     Console reflects the changes. When the verification flow is complete,
>     return to step 4.

Answer (score 4):

You should now use `authors` instead of `author`:

```
name: my_package
authors:
  - me@mail.com
  - another_author@mail.com
...
```

Comment: authors is also deprecated and Verified publishers should be used from the doc

Comment: Ah oopsy. I can't delete the answer though -_-